# Access to Windows upload file dialog

Tags: node.js, whatsapp, puppeteer

I'm using node.js **puppeteer** library to handle WhatsApp Web. I've managed to handle the entire page, except for when I try to upload a file via upload dialog.

I've tried many ways to handle the window dialog, including VBS, batch,sendkeys etc.

Is there any way that i could enter a text inside the text-line of the dialog box and press "Open" https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRVNJ.jpg][1] as well?

Here is my code up to the adding file in WhatsApp (raw code)

```
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3264.0 Safari/537.36');

page.goto('https://web.whatsapp.com/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 0 }).then(async function (response) {

await page.waitFor(networkIdleTimeout);

await page.waitFor(user_chat_selector);
await page.click(user_chat_selector);

await page.waitFor(networkIdleTimeout);
await page.keyboard.type('Testing');

await page.waitFor(networkIdleTimeout);
await page.keyboard.press('Enter');

await page.waitFor(networkIdleTimeout);
await page.waitFor(pin_attach);
await page.click(pin_attach);

await page.waitFor(networkIdleTimeout);
await page.waitFor(add_image_icon);
await page.click(add_image_icon);

//await page.waitFor(networkIdleTimeout);    
// await page.keyboard.type("a");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to open a real dialog, there is a [method for uploading files](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleuploadfilefilepaths):

```
 const elementHandle = await page.$('input');
 await elementHandle.uploadFile("/path/to/file");
```

Comment: Hi Vaviloff, thank you for your answer.

be aware that I'm trying to upload the file via WhatsApp-Web and it's not possible to upload a file like the way you suggested.

meanwhile, I do manage to write into the dialog box via VBS - Shell.AppActive and SendKeys method. the only lack is that Sendkeys doesn't work in sleep mode.

is there any solution for that, except canceling the sleep option in windows?

regards,

Gal Cohen-or

Comment: `not possible to upload a file like the way you suggested` Why? I opened Whatsapp webapp and there are two `file` inputs that can be found with `document.querySelectorAll("[type=file]")`: one for images/video, another for documents.

Comment: @Vaviloff I have tried this as well and it doesn't work for me.  Yes if i have the website open and use the document.querySelectorAll("input[type=file]"); it shows me the input, i can click it with puppeteer but it does nothing when i use .uploadFile.  It is like something happened but i don't see any changes on the site itself and i don't see that the file got accepted.  I'm actually having this same issue and i started a new question so you can see (with pics).